# How can I read the whole text file and get an output file in .dbf

Tags: foxpro

R/sir;
How do I read the whole text file and get an output file in .dbf ? (Import text file to FoxPro .dbf file.)
I'm newbie for foxpro pl. elaborate in detail.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to do it, could you please provide a little more sample of what you are attempting.  Is it a comma-separated-values list, fixed column length text, XLS (older Excel file format), XML?

You could create a temporary cursor (or permantent table) as I like to do and do any data cleanup in a temp cursor then append to a final table after things are good to go.  Then, do an append from, something like

```
create cursor C_MyTempInputDBF ;
   ( SomeColumn c(20),;
     AnotherColumn c(15),;
     etcField c(10) )

append from YourTextFile.txt TYPE SDF
```

(or type XLS, CSV, DELIMITED WITH TAB, etc... look into help on the "APPEND FROM" command).

If you are dealing with an XML file, you could do a somewhat similar import as long as its only a one-level deep of records, not complex with multiple entries per record.  That process would work with XMLTOCURSOR() function.

A little more detail and sample file content would help more too.

Answer (score 1):

**  Create a free table called lines.dbf with a single field called line which is 80 characters.

In this example the text file is from Space Track, (https://www.space-track.org/) with 3-line elements.  This snippet brings the text lines in as individual records.

Each satellite is 3 lines which become 3 records in this example.  There are 46,392 lines (records) representing 15,464 items in the catalog as of this writing.

---

use lines

dele all

pack

appe from 3le.txt fields line deli

---

**  Then they can be sliced up as per https://www.mmto.org/obscats/tle.html using SUBSTR functions and placed in appropriate fields in the final target  table.

Answer (score 0):

Or you could use the Import Wizard.

In visual Fox Pro main window, go to: Tools -> Wizards -> Import.

It's pretty simple from that point forward.

Answer (score 0):

If you are dealing with a simple text file, there is a simpler solution:

```
filetostr("c:file_to_import.txt")
```

Comment: But that won't give him a DBF, which he seems to want.